Ubuntu 24.04, AppIndicators (Panel App Tray Icon), Right Click Menu Does Not Show Up Unless Restart the Extension
The Problem
I just installed Ubuntu 24.04, but found the "AppIndicators" plugins (AppIndicator and KStatusNotifierItem Support, Ubuntu AppIndicator) does not work as expected. Specifically, LinuxQQ's app tray icon right click menu does not show up unless a restart of relevant extension is performed.

I need at least 10 reputations to post image.

an animation showing the problem, qq's tray menu does not show up unless relevant extension is restarted

relevant extension:

AppIndicator and KStatusNotifierItem Support
Ubuntu AppIndicators
Dash to Dock
Ubuntu Dock
panel scroll


I've Tried...

Re-install the system, the problem still exists.
Try this without "AppIndicator and KStatusNotifierItem Support" and "Dash to Dock", the problem still exists.
Install "AppIndicator and KStatusNotifierItem Support" and "Dash to Dock", the problem still exists.
Restart any of the relavant extension, the click menu might work afterwards but some setting might break (see I've Found...).

I've Found...

"Ubuntu AppIndicators"'s setting window looks identical to "AppIndicator and KStatusNotifierItem Support"'s.
"Ubuntu Dock"'s setting window looks identical to "Dash to Dock"'s.
Sometimes, disabling one extension breaks another's setting:

The "show overview" of "dash to dock" or "ubuntu dock" might get reset to true.
The "AppIndicator and KStatusNotifierItem Support" might error out upon disable.



Expectation
I'm expecting the "app tray icon click menu" to work without manually disabling and re-enabling plugin.
Or specifically, I'm looking for one of the two solutions:

Address the root cause, and report this to either Tencent or Canonical (or maybe both).
Having a script that disable and re-enable some extensions after system boots up to make things work.


Try whether the issue reproduces with the standard Ubuntu desktop. Mixing Gnome Shell extensions is never a good idea. To test, temporarily create a new account, see whether the issue appears when logged in into that new account.

@vanadium I tried your suggestion and confirmed that the issue still exists. And disabling and re-enabling "Ubuntu AppIndicators" brings the click menu back.

Only with this application or also with others? Add all this information to your question: use "edit". Comments are not always read and may disappear.

I had the same problem as you and what I did to solve it was to create a script that disabled and enabled the appindicator and put it in gnome-session-properties.
sleep 5
gnome-extensions disable ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
gnome-extensions enable ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com


Thanks for sharing! But I switched back to 22.04 afterward, so I don't know if this would work on my pc. But I'll accept this for now as I assume you post this because it's working.

Thanks so much for this.  I install Ubuntu 24.04.1 (X11 no Wayland) but it still has this issue.  Seriously, this is the worst LTS ever!
